# Regular expression to avoid null values

Tags: c#, regex

I dont know how to use regex ,i have seen them to be used in email validation ,Is there any way i could restrict null values by using regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^(.+)$/
```

This regex will match anything which isn't empty (require one or more character), but is it really usefull to check it with a regex ?

Comment: Empty != null, but who knows what OP wants.

Comment: @zessx then how can i restrict textbox from entering a null value which is in usercontrol

Comment: `textbox`, `usercontrol` : ok, then I guess you're using C# ? I won't be able to help you more, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. null is not a value. It indicates you that the pointer doesn't point to anything. You can use "assert", or just if(yourobject==null){}